# Mithril.js: sorting data not re-rendered if view uses subcomponent

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

I am trying to sort a list of data and reflect the change, but my view isn't refreshing if I use subcomponents to render the content.

My sort function is being called simply by a button's onclick:

```
m('button', {onclick: ctrl.sort}, 'sort'),
```

Here's a jsfiddle that replicates my issue. The first version uses a subcomponent to render.
https://jsfiddle.net/4trL6y22/

```
ctrl.names.map(function(name){
    return m(Hello, {who: name});
})
```

If the code is rewritten without the subcomponent, the view refreshes after the sort occurs: 
https://jsfiddle.net/4trL6y22/1/

```
ctrl.names.map(function(name){
    return m('h1', name);
})
```

(My real-life case is more complicated and benefits from having the subcomponent). What am I missing to bubble up this sort's diff to the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the snippet, I think you're misunderstanding how the controller function is run.

Afaiu the controller executes once when a component is created, but not on subsequent diffs. (Generally speaking, exceptions to this statement include when the `key` changes (afaiu).)

Hence, putting `options.who` directly in the view is preferable to setting it in the controller of the component (it makes it a pure component, hence why I believe it's preferable -- meaning state is maintained in less places) which fixes one of the issues.

The other issue is that the `names` property is set to the result of the `list` prop on initialisation but is never updated (although, if the change mentioned above is made then the correct functionality *appears* to happen because the `list` is updated because `sort()` performs and in-place sort -- https://jsfiddle.net/bruce_one/1qpresbf/ vs https://jsfiddle.net/bruce_one/m3c5rn92/ demonstrates what I'm trying to explain). Hence, rather than invoking the prop in the controller, instead invoke it when retrieving the value in the view.

So the two changes (and a `.slice(0)` to get make the sort non-mutating (ish)) becomes: https://jsfiddle.net/bruce_one/4trL6y22/3/

(Afaict, this is fixing your issues?)

Comment: Thanks, turning the subcomponent to a pure component did the trick. I'm still trying to understand the mechanics though. Do you mind pointing me to some documentation about how and when the controller function runs?

Comment: Hmm... I actually don't know of any to point you to (I only realised that controllers weren't invoked every time after a similar "why isn't this doing what I think it should" moment). The relevant code is [here](https://github.com/lhorie/mithril.js/blob/next/mithril.js#L749) if that helps any? :-s

Comment: Hmm, best I can find is `The controller function is called once when the component is rendered. Subsequently, the view function is called and will be called again anytime a redraw is required. The return value of the controller function is passed to the view as its first argument.` from http://mithril.js.org/mithril.component.html -- and the general controller discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to solve the problem, but you can set the redrawing strategy to "all" `m.redraw.strategy("all");`

http://mithril.js.org/mithril.redraw.html#strategy